# Downloading files from a GCE VM to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I made a Virtual Machine using Google Cloud's Debian GNU/Linux 9 server. In there, I have a script that writes and saves to an Excel (xlsx) file at a certain time every day. I have tmux installed so that it keeps running the script when I shut my pc off.

Is there a way for me to retreive this information in an easy way instead of me having to open up the server and downloading it from there. It kind of defeats the whole purpose of me making a bot. :/

Thanks!

Ps. I'm on a Windows10 desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a possible solution you can follow steps below:

1. [create a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets) at [Google Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage#benefits)
2. [install](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/installing.md#ubuntu-and-debian-latest-releases) `gcsfuse`
3. [mount](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#using) your bucket to the VM as a file system with [Cloud Storage FUSE](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse):

   ```
   bucket-fuse-mount:~$ gcsfuse bucket-fuse-mount /home/user/bucket-fuse-mount/
   Using mount point: /home/user/bucket-fuse-mount
   Opening GCS connection...
   Opening bucket...
   Mounting file system...
   File system has been successfully mounted.
   ```
4. check if you can write to mounted bucket:

   ```
   bucket-fuse-mount:~$ touch /home/user/bucket-fuse-mount/test-file
   touch: cannot touch '/home/user/bucket-fuse-mount/test-file': Input/output error
   ```

   **if you see the same error** go to `Compute Engine` -> `VM instances` -> stop your VM -> click on `NAME_OF_VM_INSTANCE` -> click `EDIT` -> go to `Access scopes` -> select `Set access for each API` -> find `Storage` and change `Read Only` to `Full` as result Cloud Storage FUSE will be able use the Compute Engine built-in service account -> start VM -> mount the bucket and check again:

   ```
   bucket-fuse-mount:~$ touch /home/user/bucket-fuse-mount/test-file
   bucket-fuse-mount:~$
   bucket-fuse-mount:~$ ls -l /home/user/bucket-fuse-mount/
   total 0
   -rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Apr  4 19:15 test-file
   ```
5. save .xlsx files to the mounted bucket (just change path in your script)
6. [download](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects) files from the bucket with `gsutil` command directly from Windows ([`gsutil`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install#install) command is a part of [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-windows)):

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://[BUCKET_NAME]/[OBJECT_NAME] [SAVE_TO_LOCATION]
   ```

   for me it looks like:

   ```
   gsutil cp gs://bucket-fuse-mount/test-file test-file 
   Copying gs://bucket-fuse-mount/test-file...
   / [1 files][    0.0 B/    0.0 B]                                                
   Operation completed over 1 objects.
   ```

   no connections to your server needed.

In addition, you can [upload](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects) files to your VM in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I do however believe I am missing permission to acces that mounted file from my script.  ```OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/home/wmj_donkers/mount/Koersen.xlsx'```. I've tried ```sudo chmod 755 -R /home/wmj_donkers/mount``` but permission is then, once again, denied.

Comment: I was able to replicate similar error. I've updated my answer with extra instructions.

Comment: Thanks so much, you've been a great help! Everything seems to be working! My python script is running in the background and the Excel file is being updated. I just can't seem to get my gsutil command working. I think it can't find a path to my python programme. ```ERROR: (gsutil) "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe": command not found```

Comment: I tried upvoting your answer but I'm new to the platform and haven't got 15 reputation yet ;)

Comment: Thank you! You've accepted my answer and I appreciate it. About your error related to python, please have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60405013) - it could be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks so much, I got everything working the way it should work! In an attempt to finish my project I asked one final question here: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61103159/using-python-to-write-google-cloud-sdk-shell-commands> if you could help me out, once again, that'd be awesome!