# Using python to write Google Cloud SDK Shell commands

Tags: python, google-cloud-sdk

I made a bot that's running on a google cloud VM. I got everything working and in order to access the data that my bot is writing out, I have to go open up the Google Cloud SDK Shell and type:

`gsutil cp gs://bucket_name/file.xlsx C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\file.xlsx`

The whole point of me going through the trouble of making a bot on a 3rd party server is to automate a process as much as i can. So I was wondering if there is any way for me to write a python script that tells the GC SDK Shell to run the command above. Or even better: run the command above when I open a certain Excel file? maybe the latter is just too good to be true though. Let me know what you think, thanks!

Python code:

````
import google
from google.cloud import storage

def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    bucket_name = "gs://bot-example"
    source_blob_name = "Koersen.xlsx"
    destination_file_name = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Koersen.xlsx"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)```
````

Answer (score 0):

Sample code using Python to download an object `file.xlsx` into your local directory `C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\file.xlsx` from a Cloud Storage bucket `gs://bucket_name`:

```
from google.cloud import storage


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):

    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    bucket_name = "gs://bucket_name"
    source_blob_name = "file.xlsx"
    destination_file_name = "C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\file.xlsx"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

More info about Cloud Storage for Python can be found in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects#storage-download-object-python).

Regarding your Excel question, you can go ahead and use the [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have tried to follow the GC documentation but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. No overwriting old files and no writing new files. Also, the word 'Client' after typing storage_client = storage.Client() is not colored in my python script. Maybe I havent pip installed a certain module? I istalled the following:                                            pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client ,
pip install --upgrade google-cloud , pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage

Comment: To install and use the Cloud Storage Python client library, you will only need `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-storage`, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-python). Then, you may want to authenticate, as per this other [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#setting_up_authentication), before using the client library. If this does not work, can you please provide some code or any error messages that you are receiving, so we can help you?

Comment: The problem is that I don't receive an error. The code executes and takes a few seconds. And then I get the ```PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Bot>``` message in my interface letting me know that the execution is done. My Google Cloud bucket is called bot-example and the file I'm trying to download from there is an Excel file called 'Koersen'. I already have a 'Koersen' Excel file on my desktop and I want to save the downloaded file to that existing location. I added my code to my first question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A few things that I've noticed looking into your code:

1. I don't see you actually calling the **download_blob()** function.
2. Remember that your function takes 3 parameters: **bucket_name**, **source_blob_name**, **destination_file_name**. These need to be specified when calling the function.
3. **bucket_name** should have the **name** of your bucket, not its link for gsutil.

---

I have modified that example accordingly and tested it. Here is what should work:

```
from google.cloud import storage


bucket_name = "<BUCKET-NAME>"
source_blob_name = "<FILE-NAME>"
destination_file_name = "<PATH-TO-THE-DESTINATION-FILE>"


def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)
    print(
        "Blob {} downloaded to {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )


download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name)
```